# What is happening to my pointer after this print statement?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

Can someone explain why the value printed by my pointer is different depending on what side of the print it is on and if there is a simple fix for this.

Note: I am very new to c (specifically pointers) and could be making a silly mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct team {
    int code;
    char *name;
} database[32];

// Set the string in database with index code
void set(int code){
    char arr[25];

    printf("Enter Team Name: ");
    gets(arr);

    database[code].name = arr;
}

// Display Teams
void display(int first, int last)
{
    printf("Name Before line: %c\n", *database[1].name);

    printf("Team Code\tTeam Name\t\tGroup Seeding\tPrimary Kit Colour\n");

    printf("Name After line %c", *database[1].name);  //Same as before different output
}

int main() {
    // Initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        database[i].code = 1;
        database[i].name = "";
    }

    set(1);
    display(0, 32);
}
```

Expected:
In: user inputted string
Out: For now it should just print the first character in the string.
Later I will change it to print the full string.

Results:
Out: Before the line displays the first char like expected.
After the line displays some unknown char

If I get rid of the set function and move that code into my main this doesn't happen, but for my full project I want it set up this way.

Comment: `arr` is a local variable. You can't use a pointer to it after the function has returned.

Comment: Basically, `char*` is not equivalent to `string` in other languages. In C you have to manually and explicitly write down almost all memory (de)allocations for strings.